# MVC: How to pass model to partialview using viewbags from a different view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Partialviewcontroller:

```
public ActionResult Groepen()
{
    DropDownModel model = new DropDownModel();
    List<GroepModel> groepen = Mapper.Map<List<GroepenWerkvorm>, List<GroepModel>>(db.GroepenWerkvorms.ToList());
    model.groepList = new SelectList(groepen, "id", "Naam");
    List<ParameterModel> parameters = Mapper.Map<List<ParametersWerkvorm>, List<ParameterModel>>(db.ParametersWerkvorms.ToList());
    model.parameterList = new SelectList(parameters, "id", "Naam");

    return View(model);
}
```

When running the partial view, works fine.

View (nor partial view but a different one):

```
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/DropDown/Groepen.cshtml")
```

=> Null reference exception because it doesn't get the proper data.

So I need to pass a model to the partialview from the current view, but how?

Tried:

```
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/DropDown/Groepen.cshtml", ViewBag.partial)
```

But then I get: Extention methods cannot be dynamically displayed.

So how do I give my partialview the proper Model so I can properly render it?

Comment: `ViewBag` is dynamic, and you need to cast it to the type. But you should not be using `ViewBag`. Create a view model, or use `Html.Action()` to call a server method that returns a partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view can contain any number of partial views. A model can contain any number of nested models. If your parent view is creating a child partial view than your view model (DropDownModel) should contain a child model that will be used as your partial views view model.

```
public class DropDownModel
{
    public string Something {get; set;}
    public ChildModel Model {get; set;}
}
```

Then your parent view Groepen will contain a partial view line like:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/DropDown/GroepenInnerPartial.cshtml", Model.ChildModel)
```

Viewbag is not needed and in my opinion would be against best practices.

**Syntax might be slightly off on partial view since I don't have an editor up

Comment: I'd figured it out ya! Thanks though, this is indeed the correct answer.